# ¿Cómo actualizar varios objetos de un array? dentro de una colección en MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo la siguiente colección como ejemplo (tickets):

```
[
 {
  "_id": "636a6f9bcf3c053c14794dd0",
  "category": "PC",
  "status": "pending",
  "description": "Descripción del ticket",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": "636a6f9bcf3c053c154353",
      "name": "usuario 1",
      "lastname": "Apellido del usuario",
      "comment": "Buen servicio" 
    },
    {
      "id": "636a6f9bcf3c053c55555",
      "name": "usuario 2",
      "lastname": "Apellido del usuario",
      "comment": "Buen servicio x2" 
    },
    {
      "id": "636a6f9bcf3c053c154353",
      "name": "usuario 1",
      "lastname": "Apellido del usuario",
      "comment": "Buen servicio x3" 
    }
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "636a6f9bcf3c053c14794dd1",
  "category": "Impresora",
  "status": "inProcess",
  "description": "Descripción del ticket",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": "636a6f9bcf3c053c154353",
      "name": "usuario 1",
      "lastname": "Apellido del usuario",
      "comment": "Excelente servicio" 
    },
    {
      "id": "636a6f9bcf3c053c55555",
      "name": "usuario 2",
      "lastname": "Apellido del usuario",
      "comment": "Excelente servicio x2" 
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

1. Yo hago una actualización al nombre del usuario desde el frontend.
2. Deseo actualizar la colección de tickets en todos los comentarios que ese usuario que estoy actualizando este involucrado.
3. Para no tener que crear otro modelo solamente para comentarios, en la colección de tickets agregue un atributo comments de tipo array donde agrego el comentario y la información del usuario que realizo el dicho comentario.

Espero y puedan ayudarme gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
db.collection.update({ //Filtras los documentos que quieres actualizar
  "comments.id": "636a6f9bcf3c053c154353",      
},
{ //Especificas que quieres cambiar (explicacion mas abajo)
  $set: {
    "comments.$[e].name": "Cambiado 1"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [ //Especificas las condiciones que debe tener el elemento para ser cambiado
    {
      "e.id": "636a6f9bcf3c053c154353" //Que el Id del usuario sea el que buscas
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

Para eso se usa el operador $[] (operador posicional filtrado): https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Donde especificamos un identificador (en este caso `e`) y luego mediante el `arrayFilters` decimos las condiciones que debe tener ese identificador para que sea cambiado.

Por ultimo especificas el modificador `multi: true` para que afecte varios documentos al tiempo.

Te dejo un ejemplo en mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/U5EfcESw33S

Comment: Wow!! muchas gracias hermano por tu respuesta lo checare el día de hoy y voy a ver si puedo hacerlo, una pregunta que no update ya no se utiliza? creo que ahora es updateMany no?

Comment: Si, puedes usar `update()` con `multi:true` (funciona también en versiones viejas de mongo), o en versiones mas recientes puedes usar el `updateMany()`

Comment: Entonces es lo mismo pero con updateMany y necesita el multi: true o no?

Comment: No, no es necesario. Si te sirvió la solución considera marcar esta respuesta como "aceptada" para así ayudar a toda la comunidad. Saludos

Comment: Me marca el siguiente error en el servidor "Could not find path "comments.0.id" in schema"

Comment: Este es el código que estoy colocando await Ticket.updateMany(
      { "comments.id": user._id },
      {
        $set: {
          "comments.$[e].name": updateUser.name,
          "comments.$[e].lastname": updateUser.lastname,
        },
      },
      {
        arrayFilters: [{ "e.id": user._id }],
      }
    );

Comment: Pero ese error no parece estar relacionado con la consulta, acabo de probar tu consulta tal cual me la mandaste, pero obviamente reemplazando el user._id, el name y el lastname por valores constantes y me funciona

Comment: Esta raro porque lo estoy checando pero me marca ese error, lo que no entiendo es podemos acceder a la propiedad id que esta dentro de un array de objetos?

Comment: Si... "comments._id" es totalmente valido... No se de donde te sale ese comments.0.id

Comment: Voy a checarlo pero gracias la ayuda bro ya acepte la respuesta saludos!